# Retreiving device twin information in an Azure function?

Tags: javascript, azure

So I have an azure function which retrieves data from a csv file. What I want to do is when retrieving that information in the azure function is to first just check if I can get details of the device twin. This is all done in javascript
So first I instantiate the details:

```
const connectionstring="<connection string>"
const devicename= "<getdevicename>".
```

Then I call the function in the middle of some other random code :

```
myfunction();
```

The function for myfunction is an async function:

```
async function myfucntion(){
var devicetwin= await registryManager.GetTwinAsync(devicename);
context.log("device is "+ devicetwin.deviceId+ "status is " + deviceTwin.status);
}
```

However none of the details appear. I have checked the devicename and it matches the twin as well.

Comment: Is the data request success?

Comment: yes the data request is successful

Comment: registryManager.GetTwinAsync(devicename).then(data => {console.log(data}).catch(err=>console.log(err)). Try and see what happens

Comment: still not getting the correct information

Comment: I guess there is sth wrong with "registryManager.GetTwinAsync(devicename)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should  modify your code like below, it works for me.

```
var Registry = require('azure-iothub').Registry;

var devicename="MyASAIoTDevice"

var registryManager = Registry.fromConnectionString("HostName=yyio*********lIlBmTU=");

async function test (){

    try {
        var devicetwin= await registryManager.getTwin(devicename);
        console.log("device is "+ devicetwin.responseBody.deviceId+ "status is " + devicetwin.responseBody.status);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
   }
}
test();
```

[image]