# Getting device twin information in an Azure function?

Tags: javascript, azure

So I have an azure function which retrieves data from a CSV file. What I want to do is when retrieving that information in the azure function is to first just check if I can get details of the device twin. This is all done in javascript in an azure function. So the function is an async function:

```
async function getDeviceTwin(){
var devicetwin= await registryManager.GetTwinAsync(deviceID);
context.log("device is "+ devicetwin.deviceId+ "status is " + deviceTwin.status);
}
```

And the function is obviously called like this:

```
getDeviceTwin()
```

And device ID is located here:

```
IotHubMessages,forEach(newmessage=>{
console.log('message':${newmessage}');
count++;
deviceID=message.deviceID;
```

When I run it in an azure function, nothing seems to be found. Why is that the case

Comment: Your mark list shocks me. If you accept answers on time, people will be more glad to assist you : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change code `devicetwin.deviceId` and `deviceTwin.status`.

Like:

```
console.log("device is "+ devicetwin.responseBody.deviceId+ "status is " + devicetwin.responseBody.status);
```

Foe more details, you can refer my answer in this post.

[Retreiving device twin information in an Azure function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65087890/retreiving-device-twin-information-in-an-azure-function)